# How to separate the contents of parentheses and make a new dataframe column?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
df['seat'].head()
```

Outputs

```
                                       seat
                   -----------------------------------------------

0    45席（1階カウンター4席、６〜８人テーブル１席2階地下それぞれ最大20人）
1                                       nan
2                                       nan
3                                       nan
4                          9席（カウンター9席、個室4席）
```

What I want is to separate the contents of the `()` and make a new column and keep the first digit as another column. Something like below:

```
     seat number                    seat arrangement
     -----------                    -----------------
0     45               1階カウンター4席、６〜８人テーブル１席2階地下それぞれ最大20人
1     nan                                  nan
2     nan                                  nan
3     nan                                  nan
4     9                          カウンター9席、個室4席
```

I think some regex might need to do this, but I can't figure out how to do this. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) would work assuming the seat number is the numeric characters before `席` and the seat arrangement is the values inside the parenthesis:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'seat': ['45席（1階カウンター4席、６〜８人テーブル１席2階地下それぞれ最大20人）',
             np.nan,
             np.nan,
             np.nan,
             '9席（カウンター9席、個室4席）']
})
```

```
new_df = df['seat'].str.extract(r'(\d+)席（(.*)）', expand=True)
new_df.columns = ['seat number', 'seat arrangement']
```

`new_df`:

```
  seat number                   seat arrangement
0          45  1階カウンター4席、６〜８人テーブル１席2階地下それぞれ最大20人
1         NaN                                NaN
2         NaN                                NaN
3         NaN                                NaN
4           9                       カウンター9席、個室4席
```